# Reading file stops after it encounters \032 character

Tags: r, csv

I am reading a csv file in R using read.csv function. The file has over 100,000 rows but R does not read all the rows. There are other posts with similar questions but they don't address my specific case. When I first time ran read.csv function, R only read 12 rows. I opened the csv file in Excel and found a special character on row 12. I manually removed that character in Excel, ran read.csv and this time R read till 150 rows where it again encountered the same character. The character looks like a period. I copied the character between hello and world (like "hello world"), ran on the R terminal. R returned "hello \032world". Any suggestion what I need to do in the read.csv function. I tried different file encoding but nothing works. Thx

Comment: That character appears to be the [substitute character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character). Maybe try using `readr::read_csv` instead. Though I can't replicate the issue with `read.csv` myself. What version of R and what OS are you using?

Comment: df = readr::read_csv("myfile.csv") did the trick. I can see all my rows now.  I am using R-4.0.2 on windows.  THANK YOU!

Any explanation what solved this problem?

Comment: I can't say for sure. Like I said, I was unable to replicate on `4.1.1`. According to that wikipedia page on certain old systems that character was sometimes used to indicate the end of file (EOF). It's possible the R file reading code has been around long enough that there was code to stop reading a file when that character occurred. I've not seen that character myself in the wild ever before. But I can't confirm that.

Comment: Is it possible that there's another special character after `\032` such that 032 wasn't the real culprit?

Comment: Visually I can see there are no other characters after \032.  I applied nchar() function and found 13 characters including \032 and 12 without \032; the same as the visual count suggests.